# Why does this pygame program freeze?

Tags: python, pygame

Below is a program using `pygame` which updates the histogram as values change.

However after a few seconds of running, the program freezes.  Can someone point out the error?

```
import random
import pygame

SCREEN_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600
FRAME_RATE = 50
BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color("white")
BAR_COLOR = pygame.Color("Black")
BUCKET_CNT = 20

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

buckets = BUCKET_CNT*[0]
bar_w = SCREEN_WIDTH / BUCKET_CNT

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

while True:
    clock.tick(FRAME_RATE)
    random.seed()
    idx = random.randrange(BUCKET_CNT)
    buckets[idx] += 1

    # Create rectangles representing bars in the histogram.
    bars = [pygame.Rect(i*bar_w,
                        SCREEN_HEIGHT - buckets[i],
                        bar_w, buckets[i]) for i in range(BUCKET_CNT)]

    # Draw bars on the background
    [pygame.draw.rect(background, BAR_COLOR, b, 5) for b in bars]

    # Blit the background
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # Show "stuff" on the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**EDIT**

These are very good suggestions. I've changed my code using to follow them, however the code still freezes. Here is how the code looks now:

```
import random
import pygame

SCREEN_SIZE = SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 600
FRAME_RATE = 50
BACKGROUND_COLOR = pygame.Color("white")
BAR_COLOR = pygame.Color("Black")
BUCKET_CNT = 20
GROWTH_RATE = 10

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

buckets = BUCKET_CNT*[0]
bar_w = SCREEN_WIDTH / BUCKET_CNT

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)

# Create rectangles representing bars in the histogram.
bars = [pygame.Rect(i*bar_w,
                    SCREEN_HEIGHT - buckets[i],
                    bar_w, buckets[i]) for i in range(BUCKET_CNT)]
random.seed()
while True:
    clock.tick(FRAME_RATE)
    idx = random.randrange(BUCKET_CNT)
    buckets[idx] += 1

    bars[idx].inflate_ip(0, GROWTH_RATE)

    # Draw bars on the background
    pygame.draw.rect(background, BAR_COLOR, bars[idx])

    # Blit the background
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

    # Show "stuff" on the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: are you getting any traceback errors?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong at a glance, but the line `[pygame.draw.rect(background, BAR_COLOR, b, 5) for b in bars]` should probably be changed. You shouldn't use list comprehensions as shorter for loops to execute methods that have side effects; not only is it weird and a bit hard to read it creates a new list every loop and then immediately throws it away. This makes the garbage collector have to work a lot harder than it needs to. The freezing might be you running out of memory and the GC stepping in to clean up; since then you'd no longer be ticking the clock (so the OS thinks you froze).

Comment: You also create a bunch of new bars each frame (and a list) which you then throw away, causing a similar problem. You might solve your problem if you forego list comprehensions entirely and just fold those two into a normal for loop over a range. Another thing that might help is keeping `bars` but moving it outside the loop and just replacing `bars[idx]` each frame, since only one bar (the one that maps to `buckets[idx]` changes each frame.

Comment: If you wanted to be even more efficient, the `Rect` class has a few [methods](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.inflate_ip) that you could use (particularly `move_ip()` and `inflate_ip()`) that will allow you to resize the rectangles instead of creating new ones. Either way, the symptom that the screen freezes is caused by the clock not ticking each frame, so there's something in your loop that's causing the clock to not get ticked.

Comment: You should provide a better analysis of what's happening. Observe the memory, debug, log messages, ...

Comment: Ok. Let me try this again. So memory is not an issue. I looked at the Windows Task Manager and saw no continuous increase in memory consumption. I also added a print statement (print 'datetime.datetime.now()') at the end of the loop and it worked even after the program froze. Looks like it is an issue with pygame itself, but I can't quite nail it. Can someone help?

Comment: Can someone run this code on their machine? This will help to narrow the problem. It could an issue with my machine.

Comment: Have you used [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to inspect what your program is doing when it hangs?

Comment: I just ran this code on my machine, and it didn't freeze. Do you have a really old or low-end machine?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I started to suspect that. I was going to run this at home (currently I'm at work). My work machine is really heavily loaded. It is running a multi-threaded test, a virtual machine (which is compiling code) and then some extra stuff. Thanks a lot for trying it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to apologize for taking everybody's time. As it turns out there is no issue with the code. My work machine was simply overloaded with various processes. It is running a multi-threaded test and a virtual machine (which is currently compiling a very large code base). That all explains why my program was freezing. Thank you  DJMcMayhem for trying out the code. A special shout out to Alex Van Leiw. Thanks to you I learned a few new things about pygame today.